# Controllador no existe - Laravel version 8.12.3

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Estoy aprendiendo de phpLaravel y cree mi primer controlador con el comando `php artisan make:controller HomeController` y en el controlador agrege el llamado de una ventana:

```
class HomeCrontoller extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('pagina_Principal');
    }
}
```

y la idea es que el `web.php` llame a la ventana al momento de asignarle la ruta asi: `Route::get('/home', 'HomeCrontoller@index');`

El problema es que cuanto ejecuto el servidor me da este error en la ruta `/home` me muestra este error.

[image: Imagen de error de no encontrar controller]

Ya le ejecute los comandos `php artisan dump-autoload` y `php artisan route:clear` y `php artisan db:seed` y la verdad no se resuelve el problema y no se por que, ya que el controlador existe y no se si lo cree mal o me falta hacer algo mas.

Gracias